# Export data from excel file to Sqlserver 2012

Tags: c#, excel

As per my requirement i want to read and export data from excel (reside on network drive) to sqlserver 2012.
I will be creating console application ( exe) using c# (.net framework 4.5).. this console
application will be schedule to run daily using window scheduler on web server.

can you let me know what is the best approach to do it...keeping performance also in mind.
 if any one has readymade code/component then please share.

Answer (score 0):

I pieced this code together from an application II wrote some time ago. It uses .NET OLEDB to import data from an Excel file, in this case into an MS-Access database, but the concept is the same for SQL-Server. You will need to adapt it to the table, Excel file and data you are using:

**Substitutions Required:**

```
 YourConnectionString
 YourSLQTable
 Your  SQL Columns: col1, col2, coln
 Your Column Valuess: @cdata1, cdata2, cdatan
 UniqueValue: the columns(s) that make your SQL table unique

 Note that parameter values must be supplied in the order they are used in the SQL statement, not in the named list, ex. New String() {"UV", "cdata1", "cdata2"}, _


Public Shared connString As String = _
    Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("xls").ConnectionString
Public Shared connStringX As String = _
   Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("xlsx").ConnectionString

Public Shared Sub ImportExcelFile(ByRef Filepath As String)
    Dim ConnectionString = IIf(Filepath.EndsWith("xlsx"), connStringX, connString)
    Try
        Using axsCon = New OleDbConnection("YourConectionString")
            axsCon.Open()
            Using m_connexcel As OleDbConnection = _
                New OleDbConnection(String.Format(ConnectionString, Filepath))
                m_connexcel.Open()
                Dim Sheetname As String = GetFirstExcelWorksheetName(m_connexcel, Filepath)
                Using cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("SELECT  * FROM [" & Sheetname & "]", m_connexcel)
                    Using oRDR As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
                        While (oRDR.Read)
                            If Common.GetScalar(axsCon, "SELECT Count(*) FROM YourSQLTable WHERE [UniqueValue]=@UV ", _
                                New String() {"UV"}, New Object() {oRDR.GetValue(0)}) = 0 Then
                                Common.ExecuteSQL(axsCon, _
                                    "INSERT INTO YouSQLTable(col1, col2, coln) " & _
                                    "VALUES(@C1,@C2,@CN)", New String() {"Cdata1", "Cdata2", "CdataN"}, _
                                        New Object() {oRDR.GetValue(0), oRDR.GetValue(1), oRDR.GetValue(2)})
                            Else
                                Common.ExecuteSQL(axsCon, _
                                    "UPDATE YourSQLTable SET col1=@cdata1,col2=@cdata2,UNiqueValue=@UV " & _
                                    "WHERE UniqueValue=@UV", New String() {"UV", "cdata1", "cdata2"}, _
                                        New Object() {oRDR.GetValue(1), oRDR.GetValue(2), oRDR.GetValue(0)})
                            End If
                        End While
                    End Using
                End Using
                m_connexcel.Close()
            End Using
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw New Exception(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

' This function is needed to find the first worksheet and may not apply to your application.

```
Private Shared Function GetFirstExcelWorksheetName(ByVal m_connexcel As OleDbConnection, ByVal Filepath As String) As String
    Try
        Dim ExcelSheets As DataTable = m_connexcel.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, New Object() {Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, "TABLE"})
        Return ExcelSheets.Rows(0).Item("TABLE_NAME")
    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw New Exception(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Function
```